# Angular Factory - Why is my variable undefined?

Tags: angularjs, undefined, angular-services

I can't figure out why my messages variable is undefined within the displayMessage function in the code below. I keep getting an error that messages is undefined. "`Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`"

```
function messageService(  ) {
  var messages = {};
  var service = {
    messages: messages,
    displayMessage: displayMessage
  };
  return service;

  function displayMessage (message, messageType) {
    messages[messageType].push(message);
  }
}
```

I am trying to use John Papa's method of laying out the variables and functions separate from the returned service, but I cannot figure out how to make messages available to the internal functions.

I have also tried this:

```
function messageService(  ) {
  /*jshint validthis: true */
  var self = this;
  self.messages = {};
  var service = {
    messages: self.messages,
    displayMessage: displayMessage
  };
  return service;

  function displayMessage (message, messageType) {
    self.messages[messageType].push(message);
  }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`messages[messageType]` is not defined anywhere. So it's undefined.

`messages` is initialized to an empty object, without any field. So `messages[messageType]` is indeed undefined.

To define it, and be able to call push() on it, you would need a line like

```
messages[messageType] = [];
```

which would initialize `messages[messageType]` to a new, empty array.

Comment: Hmmm. I see. But messageType will be a string defined by the controller. I can't hard-code that into the factory. I was going by another example where the guy had just set `alerts: {}` and then pushed to alerts with `this.alerts[type].push(message)`, where "type" is defined via a function argument. But, he was doing it all from within the return. See his fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/uberspeck/j46Yh/ How is he doing that and how could I mimic it with the Papa approach - I'm a noob. :-D

Comment: You can create the arraylazily, when adding the first element to it: `if (!messages[messageType]) { messages[messageType] = []; }`. That's what the linked jsfiddle does (with another syntax): `this.alerts[type] = this.alerts[type] || [];`

Comment: Nevermind, I see. You just define that WITHIN the displayMessage function. Sorry. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the messages object with properties that contain an empty array and you can pushing values:

```
function messageService(  ) {
  var service = {
    messages: {
      debug: [],
      info: [],
      warning: [],
      error: []
    },
    displayMessage: displayMessage
  };
  return service;

  function displayMessage (message, messageType) {
    service.messages[messageType].push(message);
  }
}
```

NOTE: Replace the messages types with yours

Comment: Thanks, I just decided to lazy load them as @JB-Nizet described.